# How to allow one static HTML file to be accessed normally and not allow WordPress to run?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site installed in public_html.

I placed a google verification file "googleb2b619edeea6dd33.html" in the public_html directory.

When I try to access this file "googleb2b619edeea6dd33.html" I get  404 Error - Page Not Found

currently my .htaccess file is as follows

What line do I put in the .htaccess file to allow accessing "googleb2b619edeea6dd33.html" only

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.3]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: For this you don't have to do anything..  Just make sure the google verification file is placed in root folder. 

/public_html/googleverificiation.html

Comment: that is what I did but the WordPress page is displayed with 404 Error - Page Not Found

Comment: is your WP site pointing to  public_html or  to a sub folder under public_html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it was my mistake. It was returning the file contents. But the file contents was wrong.

I had used "save link as" when the google verification file was absent on the web server. So it downloaded the 404 error html.